# Update the Base Class attributes when instantiate Child class C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I want the following, is it possible in C#

```
public class BaseClass
{
       public string Name {get;set;}
       public DateTime Login {get;set;}
}

public class ChildA : BaseClass
{
       public string SchoolName{get; set;}
       public string ClassName{get; set;}
}

public class childB : BaseClass
{
       public string StreetAdrees{get; set;}
}
```

Now I want that if I create an instance of any child class Name="John" and Login "2013-12-12" or from database already set its irritating to set these attribute for every class

just like that

```
ChildA obj=new ChildA();

obj.Name and obj.Login already have Data
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify constructor in base class, then create constructors in child classes which inherit from base classes constuctor like below

```
public class ChildA : BaseClass
{
       public ChildA():base(){}
       public string SchoolName{get; set;}
       public string ClassName{get; set;}
}

public class BaseClass
{
      public BaseClass()
      {
          //set Data
           .....
      }
   ....
}
```

read more about [base keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx)

Comment: My all classes inherited from the same class how can i developed that when i create a object of any child class attributes of base class have specific or data 

and these attributes need to be fill from database using entity frame work 5 so i do not need to create connection again and again

Comment: @WaqasIdrees check now

Comment: Thanks its works fine for me :) Please vote me up that increase my reputaion

Answer (score 0):

In the example below, children would actually point to the same instance of base

The example uses cache, but it could be anything else (session, application state, etc).

```
public class BaseClass
{
    private string _name;
    private DateTime _login;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return Instance._name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
        }
    }
    public DateTime Login 
    {
        get
        {
            return Instance._login;
        }
        set
        {
            _login = value;
        }
    }

    public static BaseClass Instance
    {
        get 
        {
            // check if null, return a new instance  if null etc...
            return HttpContext.Current.Cache["BaseClassInstance"] as BaseClass;                
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("BaseClassInstance", value);
        }
    }
}

public class ChildA : BaseClass
{
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
}

public class childB : BaseClass
{
    public string StreetAdrees { get; set; }
}
```

testing it:

```
BaseClass.Instance = new BaseClass() { Login = DateTime.Now, Name = "Test" };

ChildA ch = new ChildA();

ChildA ch2 = new ChildA();

childB chb = new childB();

Response.Write(ch.Login.Millisecond);
Response.Write("<BR/>");
Response.Write(chb.Login.Millisecond);
```

Result:

906

906